# Get url param no longer works when using add_rewrite_rule

Tags: url-rewriting, pods-framework

I'm using WordPress admin to create a page (named `get-region-page`), in which Pod shortcode is used to retrieve the URL parameter. For example:

```
[pods name="region" slug="{@get.regionparam}" field="region_name"]
```

With a redirection 301 to the URL `/get-region-page&regionparam=$region_slug`, the Pod shortcode works fine.

The problem arrives when I need to create a rewrite rule for that page in `functions.php` (with `1234` is the page ID for `get-region-page`):

```
add_rewrite_rule('({some-custom-regex})/?$','index.php?page_id=1234&regionparam=$matches[1]','top');
```

...the parameter becomes `null`. I can no longer retrieve the URL parameter.
But if I try this PHP code in the WordPress template of the page, the parameter is still there:

```
echo get_query_var('regionparam');
```

Remark, this one does not work either in the PHP template:

```
echo $_GET['regionparam'];
```

So I wonder if there is some equivalent Pod shortcode for `get_query_var('regionparam')` for my first Pod shortcode to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, rather a workaround for my problem.
The url parameter can still be retrieved by using `$GLOBALS[ ‘any’ ]` thanks to this document: https://docs.pods.io/displaying-pods/magic-tags/special-magic-tags/.
So instead of using `$_GET['any']`as in my previous shortcode:

```
[pods name="region" slug="{@get.regionparam}" field="region_name"]
```

I just replace it with `$GLOBALS`:

```
[pods name="region" slug="{@globals.regionparam}" field="region_name"]
```

In order for the parameter `regionparam` to be available as global, I needed to add this filter in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter("query_vars", function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "regionparam";
    $vars[] .= "otherParamsIfNeeded";
    return $vars;
});
```

And in the other functions, I replace the old `$_GET['regionparam']` by `get_query_var('regionparam')`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my question was not well formatted and can not modify it.
Here's the more readable one:

I'm using WP Admin DIVI builder to create a page (named *get-region-page*), in which Pod shortcut is used to retrieve the url param. For example:

```
[pods name="region" slug="{@get.regionparam}" field="region_name"]
```

which gives apparently the same result as using these in the php template of the page:

```
$_GET['regionparam']
```

With a redirection 301 to that page url: */get-region-page&**regionparam**=$region_slug*, everything works fine, I can retrieve the url parameter.
The problem arrives when I replace the 301 redirection with a rewrite rule for that page in ***functions.php*** (with 1234 the page id for *get-region-page*):

```
add_rewrite_rule('({some-custom-regex})/?$','index.php?page_id=1234&regionparam=$matches[1]','top');
```

...the parameter ***regionparam*** becomes null. Only this works:

```
get_query_var('regionparam');
```

but no longer this

```
$_GET['regionparam'];
```

So I wonder if there is any way I can retrieve that get_query_var('regionparam') for my first pod shortcut to rework again in DIVI builder?
Thank you for your help!